# Using prompts in Select Case statements

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I want to use select case for my prompts. Condition is that when the prompt :4 = 'I' then prompt :5 equals all of its values, and I use the code below but i receive the following error.

Error in running query because of SQL Error, Code=936, Message=ORA-00936: missing expression (50,380)

```
2 = 2 AND (CASE :5
WHEN :4 = 'I' AND :5 = ' ' 
THEN :5 = '%' 
END)
```

Anything wrong with my case statemnt?

Answer (score 3):

There are two different syntaxes for `CASE`:

```
CASE value1
WHEN value2 THEN expression1
WHEN value2 THEN expression2
            ELSE expression3
END
```

and:

```
CASE
WHEN boolean_expression THEN expression1
WHEN boolean_expression THEN expression2
                        ELSE expression3
END
```

Note: The first statement can be converted to the second as

```
CASE
WHEN value1 = value2 THEN expression1
WHEN value1 = value3 THEN expression2
                     ELSE expression3
END
```

You are mixing these two syntaxes and it is invalid SQL.

You appear to want:

```
:5 = CASE WHEN :4 = 'I' AND :5 = ' ' THEN '%' END
```

However, even that will not work as bind variables are set once and are not re-evaluated so your logic would be:

```
   (     ( :4 = 'I' AND :5 = ' ' ) AND :5 = '%' )
OR ( NOT ( :4 = 'I' AND :5 = ' ' ) AND :5 = NULL )
```

Since `:5` cannot ever be both `' '` and `'%'` then that branch of the logic can never be true and anything (including `NULL`) is never equal to `NULL` so the second branch of the logic is also never true; therefore your expression will never match anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an expression like this

```
decode(:4,'I',:5,SOMEVALUEORFIELD) = :5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your `case` expression:

```
(CASE :5 WHEN :4 = 'I' AND :5 = ' ' THEN :5 = '%' 
 END)
```

I cannot figure out what you really want.  Both the `CASE :5` and the `:5 = '%'` are improper. Perhaps:

```
(CASE WHEN :4 = 'I' AND :5 = ' ' THEN '%' 
 END) as :5
```

However, you don't normally use parameters for column aliases.

Comment: Both CASE statements are invalid: for the first, you can't use `CASE value WHEN boolean_expression THEN ...` you either need to use `CASE value WHEN value THEN ...` or `CASE WHEN boolean_expression THEN ...`; for the second, `AS :bind_variable` is invalid (and so would `2 = 2 AND CASE ... END AS alias` also be invalid).

Comment: @MT0 . . . If `:5` is a bind variable, then it is incorrect (hence my last comment).  Similar syntax can be used in some applications for string replacement, in which case the code would merely look unorthodox.  As for the first, the answer was not properly edited.